# SDL window crashes when mouse goes below a certain point

Tags: c++, graphics-programming, sdl2

I added code to check the rgb values of my surface, and whenever i call the function it seems to work fine! the only problem is that whenever the mouse goes under y = 400 the entire window crashes... Right now the program outputs the rgb color of the pixel on the screen, and when it goes below 400 one or all of the pixel values are 0, and then the program crashes. I have no ideas why this is happening. Any help is appreciated! Heres the github repo! https://github.com/jcsq6/SDLGame not much has been done except a couple classes to make my life easier in SDL :)

```
int* texture::getPixel(int x, int y){
    static int Color[4];
    SDL_PixelFormat *fmt;
    Uint32 temp, pixel;
    Uint32 *pixels = (Uint32 *)Surface->pixels;
    Uint8 red, green, blue, alpha;

    fmt = Surface->format;
    SDL_LockSurface(Surface);
    pixel = pixels[(y * Surface->w) + x];
    SDL_UnlockSurface(Surface);

    temp = pixel & fmt->Rmask;  
    temp = temp >> fmt->Rshift;
    temp = temp << fmt->Rloss;
    red = (Uint8)temp;

    temp = pixel & fmt->Gmask; 
    temp = temp >> fmt->Gshift;
    temp = temp << fmt->Gloss;
    green = (Uint8)temp;

    temp = pixel & fmt->Bmask; 
    temp = temp >> fmt->Bshift; 
    temp = temp << fmt->Bloss; 
    blue = (Uint8)temp;

    temp = pixel & fmt->Amask;
    temp = temp >> fmt->Ashift;
    temp = temp << fmt->Aloss; 
    alpha = (Uint8)temp;

    Color[0] = red;
    Color[1] = green;
    Color[2] = blue;
    Color[3] = alpha;

    return Color;
```

}

it's worth noting that when I call this function, the input y and x values are the mouse's position.

Comment: Are you sure that `surface->format->BytesPerPixel == 4`?

Comment: i checked, and i think the bits per pixel was 24, so no that'd make the bytes = 3, why is that important?

Comment: Use `BytesPerPixel` I think, and use that to inform what you need to cast the `Surface->pixels` to.

Comment: If you only have 24 bits per pixel, you may not have an alpha value. Check what `Amask` is. If it's 0, that makes sense. You only have RGB.

Comment: why would that be causing a crash?

Comment: Under "Remarks" on [this](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_PixelFormat#bytesperpixel) page, you can see what data type to cast the pixels to. Casting to a `Uint32*` only makes sense if each pixel is 4 bytes wide. If each pixel is 3 bytes wide, then you need to take your pixels as a 3-tuples of `Uint8`.

Comment: yes, i checked and the alpha is 0

Comment: If you have N pixels, and each takes up 3 bytes, then your `Surface->pixels` array is only 3*N bytes long. If you cast it to a `Uint32*`, and try to access any of the pixels in the last 1/4 of the pixel array, you'll be going past this N*3 array size, since you'll be accessing values up to N*4 away from the start of the array.

Comment: What's `BytesPerPixel`? That's the important value according to the documentation. I suspect it's 3.

Comment: yeah i assumed i was just reaching outside of the pixels array, and yes 3 bytes per pixel

Comment: What should I change in the code? do i need to change all of the Uint32 to Uint8s? and what would i change all of the Uint8's to?

Comment: Hang on writing up the full answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [SDL Documentation](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_PixelFormat#bytesperpixel), your casting of

```
Uint32 *pixels = (Uint32 *)Surface->pixels;
```

only works if your `surface->format->BytesPerPixel == 4`. Your `BytesPerPixel` appears to be 3. Another clue as to it being only 3 bytes is that your `aMask == 0`.

Your pixel array is only `3*N` bytes wide, where `N` is the number of pixels. Since you're casting to a `Uint32*`, any accesses into the array assume that each pixel is 4 bytes wide, and you'll access elements between `[pixels, pixels + 4*N)`. Your actual array only takes up space between `[pixels, pixels + 3*N)`.

According to the SDL Doc linked above, your bytes should therefore be accessed as 3-tuples of `Uint8`. Change your code like this:

```
int* texture::getPixel(int x, int y){
    static int Color[4];
    Uint8 *pixels = (Uint8 *)Surface->pixels;
    Uint8 red, green, blue;

    SDL_LockSurface(Surface);
    red   = pixels[(y * Surface->w) + x    ];
    green = pixels[(y * Surface->w) + x + 1];
    blue  = pixels[(y * Surface->w) + x + 2];
    SDL_UnlockSurface(Surface);

    // since each R, G, B value takes up a full Uint8, I'm not
    // sure if you need to mask, downshift, then upshift the values
    // at all.

    // setting opacity to 0xff, for full-opacity

    Color[0] = red;
    Color[1] = green;
    Color[2] = blue;
    Color[3] = 0xff;

    return Color;
}
```

Let me know how this works. I don't have any experience with SDL, so this may need adjustment.

Your use of a `static` array to return the colors is suspect, but I kept that to mimic your code. It's also strange to stick color values: `Uint8`s, into an array of `int`s, but I kept that as well to match your code. I didn't know what you were using this array for, and wanted to change as little as possible.

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks for your help!

Comment: Good to know. I'm curious what values your `R/G/BMask/Shift/Loss` have, if any.

Comment: Yeah that'd be interresting. idk

Comment: Well I mean you can inspect them in your debugger or output them `Surface->format->Rmask;` etc

Comment: Because if the mask, loss, or shift have values and we're ignoring them (as my code currently does), then your colors could be washed out

Comment: no the colors look fine to me... i dont think they have values

Comment: "i dont think they have values" why assume when you can check?

Comment: you are correct they have no value

Comment: Cool, thanks for confirming. Like I said earlier I have no experience with SDL so I was curious. Good luck with your game!!!

Comment: thx for your help!